# Xcode editor area not working right

Tags: xcode, editor

I've been having this weird bug where when I click on some implementation files in Xcode, the editor area will freeze up and not let me move the cursor or scroll and sometimes flashes blank.  The only way I've been able to edit it is to copy and paste into text editor.  I've tried deleting all derived data but that did not help.  Any suggestions?  I'm running Xcode 4.6.2

Comment: Yeh, I'm getting this too - pain in the ar5e...

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem again and again. I filed a bug report on Apple's bug reporter system. They asked me for my project, what the f***?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue and it almost drove me to insanity!

By chance I discovered that this bug seems to be caused by the placeholders of XCode's code completion.

The workaround: open the "offending" file in another editor and remove the placeholders, which are displayed as `<#placeholder#>`.
This has solved the problem for me… but it doesn't change the fact that this is a nasty bug.

I'm using XCode 4.6.3 btw.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this worked for me (XCode 4.6.3). The files that were playing up had LOTS of commented out methods, near the bottom of each file (which seemed to coincide with when the scrolling would suddenly stop working!!)

I deleted these comments in TextWrangler and reloaded in XCode - I am now able to view/edit the entire file, scrolling up and down easily. Hope this works for you.

Comment: I don't have a lots of uncommented methods but still get this issue after scrolling above line 1000 is larger source files.

Comment: if you can post your project somewhere (not sure how to do this privately, easily), I can see if it happens with my XCode? All I can suggest.

Comment: Sorry but its an entirely private project. If i experience it on one of my open source libraries then i will contact you here. Thank you

Comment: «each file» --> do you mean the source files (eg: file.h, file.cpp, etc.) of a project? I experience the same scroll freeze but can't locate `<#placeholder#>` in any of my project source files...

Comment: @Daan it’s not the literal word “placeholder”. Search for `<#` or `#>` and see what turns up. The word between them will be different every time.